# my screen is broken on my moto g. How can i put it into discovery mode on bluetooth?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, touchscreen

My motorola moto g smartphone has broken screen.  Is there any way to connect to pc and sync my music.? I cant see the screen to turn bluetooth on so i cant get it into discovery mode.

Comment: Is "USB debugging" enabled?

Answer (score 1):

To turn on bluetooth with root access it is this command:

> adb shell su -c service call bluetooth_manager 6

To turn off Bluetooth with root access it is this command:

> adb shell su -c service call bluetooth_manager 8

Comment: On which Android version(s) have you tested these commands? That service doesn't exist in Android 4.2.1. What's more, 6 and 8 are numbers for the functions which may vary in Android releases. It is better to mention Android version for which your commands would work.

Comment: I have tested on a a Samsung Galaxy tab pro with a rooted android 4.4.2. I have also tested this on a nexus 4. Sorry for the lack of backround information and references.http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/bluetooth/IBluetoothManager.java/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044700/android-4-4-service-bluetooth-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control your Android device from PC then you can use [Vysor](http://www.vysor.io/)

Chrome extension : [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor-beta/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm)

Demo Video : [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yJeTrOnFYg)

Comment: Vysor can be used to mirror the screen but needs USB debugging enabled.